# Any software for designing ER diagrams or relationship for database

Tags: mysql, database, schema, entity-relationship

I want make the ER diagram or database schema . Is there any software which can help me in drawing those relations and links with some samples for most used tasks on we

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Edraw...It is paid but you can use evaluation version.
You can get information from http://www.edrawsoft.com/

All most all diagrams are available to draw in this software.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL Workbench can help you with that. http://wb.mysql.com/  There is an ERD tool that can read your existing db and create a diagram you can then modify.  It will also synchronize changes to your database if that is your desire as well.

Comment: i need reverse . i mean first i want to draw the diagram , have a look at it and then i have to make the database. so initially i wont have any DB . so i want something where i can write the table , attributes , methods andthen link with other table using GUI

Comment: MySQL workbench would let you do that too.  You don't have to have the db to begin with.  But you can build the model in a gui way there, and then ultimately create the db based on that diagram.

Comment: Hi Pasha, I think what you mean is: you want to forward engineer from ER model to database (usually reverse engineer means generating model from database).

Answer (score 0):

I use [Dia](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/) for my ER diagrams. Dia can also be used for other drawing of similar style, including flowcharts etc.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise Architect is probably more expensive than you are looking for but it has everything.

Answer (score 0):

Offer Entity Relation (ER) model for information storage formations (teams), players and football teams matches

The minimum required entities and relations should be:

- teams (teams)
- Players
- Matches
- The position of players
- Races

Relationship between the entities is as follows:

- A player may play in more matches
- In match play more players

The team has 11 players minimum. In match play 2 teams. A team has many players and a player can only play for a team in a particular match. A player may play in zero or more matches. The design should allow the maintenance of records for the position which each player has played in his team in a specific game and has scored many goals in the match.

Information should be recorded and who was host of the match, the match date and time and which should be recorded in the match race was developed (eg Champions League, Premiership, FA Cup, etc.).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! But... are you sure you are posting this in the right place? This does not look like an answer to the question.